# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my diagnostic view of my build output shows this conflict

> There was a conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". (TaskId:20)
>    "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not. (TaskId:20)
>     References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll]. (TaskId:20)

I got here by adding the RestSharp nuget package.  I was not having an issue until I installed this and I think one of the pieces that came with it may have caused this issue.  I tried to uninstall it but that did not work.

Comment: Have you setting proper binding redirect to version 4.1.1.2? If the binding redirect set incorrectly, 4.0.0.0 may be used as primary assembly.

Comment: I can not find the binding that references 4.0.0
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Solution:  I removed the binding from the config file.  Now everything works.  So there is something you can try.

Comment: @Dan thank you for providing your solution in the comments, it helped me in this exact same scenario. It may be worth you putting this as an answer and marking it as such for future reference for others! :) Thanks!

Comment: do not use any bindingRedirect  for System.Net.Http , remove from config file and do not think witch version is in use, this is managed by your system

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Installing Nuget Package: System.Net.Http version 4.3.3 installs the correct Version=4.1.1.2

this will result in the following reference in your project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I am marking this as an answer.  Although removing the reference worked for me it may be covering some other problem.  Please try both methods and pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: @Dan What did you end up doing long-term?

Comment: I actually had to copy the System.Net.Http.dll to the `../bin/Debug` folder to get it to work, somehow installling the NuGet package did not put that dll there. Also see https://gertjanvanmontfoort.blogspot.com/2017/11/systemnethttp-dll-version-problems.html

Comment: I fixed this using this solution                                                                            <configuration>  
   <runtime>  
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, some projects will force you to reference `System.Net.Http` 4.2.0.0.

When you install from nuget (version 4.3.3) and your `System.Net.Http` is 4.1.1.2, there will be a conflict.

So in your web.config or app.config, **you can change to 4.1.1.2 or 4.2.0.0**, depending on which version was copied to the bin folder at runtime.

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Pretty much solved it for me--the actual config that worked for me(Azure App Service): https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/784#issuecomment-437003960

Comment: Note: your production (or server where you deploy code) usually don't have VS2017, so its version will be 4.1.1.2, and your local dev (with vs install) will be 4.2.0.0

Comment: Sendgrid lib was dependent on the System.Net.Http. I had to upgrade the .Net Framework from 4.6.1 to 4.7.1

Answer (score 16):

After upgrading from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 we started getting this error. The final solution was to go to the web config file, find this:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

and replace it with this:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The change done above was just this: `newVersion="4.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 12):

I'm using **.NET Framework 4.7.2** and **Visual Studio 15.5**. When I upgraded **System.Net.Http 4.3.3** to **4.3.4**, I received the "could not load" error:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

I got past that only to get a *FileNotFoundException*:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
>   not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This thread in the **.NET Core** project on GitHub discusses this issue, and I found this post in the **.NET Core** project on GitHub to be very helpful:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773#issuecomment-350036434

My (poor) summary: Microsoft is trying to eliminate the need for the **System.Net.Http** NuGet package since it was a workaround for other release issues. **.NET Framework 4.7.1** and **VS 15.5** have changes that (should?) eliminate the need for it and the associated bindings altogether.

I deleted the **System.Net.Http** NuGet package from my projects, and added references to the **System.Net.Http** included with **.NET Framework 4.7.2**, and everything's ship-shape again.

Comment: I have the error using VS 2019 and Net Framework 4.8, using System.Net.Http NuGet package. Using binding redirect not working.

Comment: Right. Try following my recommendation to remove the NuGet package and the bindings. My VS2019/4.8 project works fine without them.

Answer (score 12):

**Root Cause:** You normally get such issue when you take the reference of certain third party library in your application.

*For example, you took the reference of **RestSharp** (A third-party library) from NuGet. That RestSharp may have used the reference of `System.Net.Http` `4.2.0.0` version. And your project has also taken the reference to `System.Net.Http` `4.0.0.0` (From GAC). Now when you run the application & try to call any method which is using **RestSharp**, at the same time Runtime (CLR) tries to locate the `System.Net.Http` assembly with version `4.2.0.0` & when it fails to locate the desired version, it throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` exception with below error message.*

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here you can see [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)?

**Solution:**
Just add below configuration in the `web.config` or `app.config` of your startup project.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This configuration instructs the runtime to resolve `System.Net.Http` assembly with `4.0.0.0` version only, whenever it looks for this assembly for any version between `0.0.0.0` to `4.2.0.0`.

Here is the complete schema:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The system.net.http libraries are now distributed as part of the .Net Standard Framework and this can cause issues, generally when you update the Nuget package to a newer version.

The solution that worked for me was to remove the System.Net.Http package (and the Formatters package that depends on it) from Nuget, and delete all references to the system.net.http libraries in app.config (they'll often be dependantAssemblies).

Lastly, edit your project file to add a reference to http from the framework like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not so good but alternate solution than using *bindingRedirect*-
If you have-

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" /></startup>
```

in App.config, then removing "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" property helps by not reverting to old CLR.