# Google Sheets Api v4 Quickstart Tutorial -- System.net.http not found even after redirect

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

I;m currently working on a project that requires me to read and write data from google sheets. Hence, I started with the **[Google Sheets Api (v4) Quick start Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) for C#**. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and have the latest versions of all nuget packages.

I have followed the tutorial step-by-step, but instead of creating a Console Application, I created a Windows Form Application. The code and other steps were followed exactly as written.

When run inside the IDE, the code runs as expected. However, when published and then run outside the IDE, the system cannot find System.Net.HTTP.

```js
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApp1.exe
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After researching and trying the solutions posted in other similar questions (which did not work) I landed on a StackOverflow post suggest redirecting older version of System.Net.Http to the latest version. However, this did not work.

[App.config with redirection code (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhqMh.png)

Here is my current code:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
            String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();


        
    }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any help to fix this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the binding from the config file as stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149345/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http#comment81248971_47149345).

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I just tried it. Unfortunately it did not work. Thanks for answering in any case.