# The type 'HttpClient' exists in both System.Net.Http Version=4.0.0.0 and System.Net.Http Version=4.1.1.2

Tags: c#, reference, nuget-package

I'm having an issue with following build error in VS2017

```
  Error CS0433: The type 'HttpClient' exists in both 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' (20, 26)
```

I have been trying the following:

- Update all existing references to 4.1.1.2
- Install 4.1.1.2 to all projects in solution
- Added binding redirects to all projects

I'm for sure missing something, but what?
Any way to find what is locking it to 4.0.0.0?

Comment: RestSharp installation? You have a binding conflict in a dependent Assembly configuration. See this: [System.Net.Http dll version problems](https://gertjanvanmontfoort.blogspot.com/2017/11/systemnethttp-dll-version-problems.html) and this: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149345/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http). Some manual editing required.

Comment: @Jimi RestSharp came to my mind, but i would like to solve the root case if possible
Build folder outputs System.Net.Http with version 4.6.25705.1 so should be fine

Comment: @mjwills Consolidate didn't help, been going through packages and also updating ones safe to update etc but error still there

Comment: If you load the Package Manager, is anything shown in the `Consolidate` tab?

Comment: @mjwills No, nothing is shown

Comment: Refactoring and removing some dependencies solved the issue
But now i have code referencing System.Net.Http, but without a reference to it, and it is still working
Probably from other, indirect references?