# Npgsql: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.0.0' on IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, iis, npgsql

My Web API is running on IIS 8.5 with .NET 4.6.1 installed. I added a new controller that connects to PostgreSQL database using [Npgsql NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql).

Now I'm getting an exception on every request to that controller in production (on my local machine everything works as expected):

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__154.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__152.MoveNext()

I changed `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `true` in the application pool, but that did not solve the problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

**UPDATE**

If I add `System.Net.Sockets` but not version 4.2.0.0 I get an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: In the error: `The system cannot find the file specified`. Does System.Net.Sockets ship with your software?

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149345/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http

Comment: @Martin It does not. There is no `System.Net.Sockets` library in by `bin` folder on my machine (where API works). I could not find that library in my system. In NuGet, there is a package, but there is no v. 4.2.0.

Comment: @FIL You may need to install it on the server in order for your application to work there

Comment: can you share ur web.config?

Comment: is there anything which says bindingRedirect?

Comment: @Gauravsa Each `dependentAssembly` in `assemblyBinding` has `bindingRedirect`. About 20 entries... If I add `System.Net.Sockets` as `dependentAssembly` with `bindingRedirect` to v.4.3.0, my API stops working (error 500).

Comment: ok. can you try removing "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" and restart the application

Comment: I tried, still the same error.

Comment: try to set load user profile to true in iis application pool advance setting or rebuild and redeploy ALL Dependents DLL files.